# Automating creation of SQL database with specific name

Tags: sql-server, windows

To start things of am not a programmer in any regards, Im that one guy who know how to click better on computers so I was asked to check what i could do about application that was bought and set up on our company server.
On the first day of a new month application stoped working and as its turned out it was the first month without post Implementation support, as i checked I notice that application is trying to write data to a database that dont exist, manually creating that particular database resolved the issue.
Right now im trying to figure out the way to automate this task - what i need to achive is to create a new database with month and year implementend in its name. example:  name0220.
Can someone point me in a direction i need to go to script something like this?
Server is on MSSQL Express 2016 on Windows Server 2012 Foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a [`SQLCMD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) example with a query to create the database with the month and year embedded in the name.

```
SQLCMD -Q"DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE DATABASE [name' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), N'MMyy') + N']';EXEC sp_executesql @sql;"
```

SQL Server Express doesn't have the SQL Agent scheduler like other SQL Server editions so you will need to schedule a script to run monthly using Windows task scheduler or similar.

Comment: Yes! Thank You, just tested that query and its working as intended :)
That was a blazing fast replay, thank you again.
As i understande if we had SQL Standard we could scheduel that script in Agent insted windows task scheduler, right?